# Undefined index error in array

Tags: php, mysql

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT* FROM {$this->vartotojai_lentele} WHERE username='{$data['username']}'";

    $result = array();
    $result = mysql::select($query);

    $ulvl = $result["userlevel"];
    echo $ulvl;
    var_dump($result); die();
```

Error and dump:

```
Notice: Undefined index: userlevel in Notice: Undefined index: userlevel in *.php on line 114
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["userid"]=> string(2) "18" ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(32) "******" ["userlevel"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

I'm trying to asign ***$result["userlevel"]*** to another variable, but I get this error. I'm new in PHP and I've been searching how to fix this problem, but I couldn't find anything. What's the problem here? Seems like my ***$result*** array isn't empty.

FIXED:
"$ulvl = $result[0]["userlevel"];. 0 is the first row, userlevel the column."

Thank you everyone.

Comment: you are missing a space between `SELECT` and `*`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) instead.

Comment: `$ulvl = $result[0]["userlevel"];`. 0 is the first row, userlevel the column.

Comment: @FlashThunder Oh right, thank you

Comment: @jh1711 Oh god! Thank you so much haha. I've been trying to fix this error for like an hour.